# Joomla upgrade: 3.10.11 to 4.x

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x, update, migration, apache

I am trying to upgrade my development server from 3.10.11 (which works fine) to 4.x in preparation for Joomla 3.x going out of support in August 23.

When I do run the live update, I get an alert box in my browser saying that the server was unable to write the file:

`/var/www/html/api/components/com_banners/src/Controller/BannersController.php`

This is the first file in alphabetical order that doesn't exist on the server.  So I assume that in some way the apache user (the user that my web server runs as) isn't able to create either a new file or a new directory in that folder.

The `owner:group` of the folder `/var/www/html is apache:apache` and I have tried setting permissions to `775`, but I still get the same message.

Normally as I am running fedora I would expect selinux to be the culprit of this kind of error but running `setenforce 0` doesn't help.

I am fairly sure this isn't a Joomla issue so much as that I have misconfigured my server somehow.  That said I can't work out at all what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the extension RSFirewall for Joomla By RSJoomla.

To solve the issue I added an 'exception'.

I specified that the component named 'Joomla! Update' could bypass all aspects of the firewall.

After that I was able to use the live update.